# Python - calling ancestor methods when multiple inheritance is involved

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Edit: I'm using Python 3 (some people asked).

I think this is just a syntax question, but I want to be sure there's nothing I'm missing.  Notice the syntax difference in how Foo and Bar are implemented.  They achieve the same thing and I want to make sure they're really doing the same thing.  The output suggests that there are just two ways to do the same thing.  Is that the case?

Code:

```
class X:

    def some_method(self):
        print("X.some_method called")

class Y:

    def some_method(self):
        print("Y.some_method called")

class Foo(X,Y):

    def some_method(self):
        X().some_method()
        Y().some_method()
        print("Foo.some_method called")

class Bar(X,Y):

    def some_method(self):
        X.some_method(self)
        Y.some_method(self)
        print("Bar.some_method called")

print("=== Fun with Foo ===")
foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance.some_method()

print("=== Fun with Bar ===")
bar_instance = Bar()
bar_instance.some_method()
```

Output:

```
=== Fun with Foo ===
X.some_method called
Y.some_method called
Foo.some_method called
=== Fun with Bar ===
X.some_method called
Y.some_method called
Bar.some_method called
```

PS - Hopefully it goes without saying but this is just an abstract example, let's not worry about *why* I'd want to call some_method on **both** ancestors, I'm just trying to understand the syntax and mechanics of the language here.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't the same.  `X()` creates an object of class `X`.  When you do `X().someMethod()` you create a new object and then call the method on that object, not on `self`.  `X.someMethod(self)` is what you want, since that calls the inherited method on the same object.

You will see the difference if your method actually does anything to the `self` object.  For instance, if you put `self.blah = 8` into your method, then after `X.someMethod(self)` the object you call it on will have the `blah` attribute set, but after `X().someMethod()` it will not.  (Instead, you will have created a new object, set `blah` on that, and then thrown away that new object without using it, leaving the original object untouched.)

Here is a simple example modifying your code:

```
>>> class X:
... 
...     def some_method(self):
...         print("X.some_method called on", self)
... 
... class Y:
... 
...     def some_method(self):
...         print("Y.some_method called on", self)
... 
... class Foo(X,Y):
... 
...     def some_method(self):
...         X().some_method()
...         Y().some_method()
...         print("Foo.some_method called on", self)
... 
... class Bar(X,Y):
... 
...     def some_method(self):
...         X.some_method(self)
...         Y.some_method(self)
...         print("Bar.some_method called on", self)
>>> Foo().some_method()
('X.some_method called on', <__main__.X instance at 0x0142F3C8>)
('Y.some_method called on', <__main__.Y instance at 0x0142F3C8>)
('Foo.some_method called on', <__main__.Foo instance at 0x0142F3A0>)
>>> Bar().some_method()
('X.some_method called on', <__main__.Bar instance at 0x0142F3C8>)
('Y.some_method called on', <__main__.Bar instance at 0x0142F3C8>)
('Bar.some_method called on', <__main__.Bar instance at 0x0142F3C8>)
```

Note that when I use `Foo`, the objects printed are not the same; one is an X instance, one is a Y instance, and the last is the original Foo instance that I called the method on.  When `Bar` is used, it is the same object in each method call.

(You can also use `super` in some cases to avoid naming the base classes explicitly; e.g., `super(Foo, self).someMethod()` or in Python 3 just `super().someMethod()`.  However, if you have a need to directly call inherited methods from two base classes, `super` might not be a good fit.  It is generally aimed at cases where each method calls `super` just once, passing control to the next version of the method in the inheritance chain, which will then pass it along to the next, etc.)

Comment: So glad I asked, and how dumb that I didn't realize Foo's implementation was creating new instances of X and Y!  So if creating new instances was not my intent, Bar's implementation is preferred - correct?

Comment: @MatthewLund: Yes, with the qualification I and @Marcin gave that actually using `super` may be better than either, in a real-world application.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should be using new-style classes. If this is Python 3, you are; if you are using Python 2, you should inherit from `object` (or some other new-style class).
2. The usual way to invoke ancestor methods is using `super`. Read about it in the standard docs, and the other excellent articles on how it operates. It is never recommended to invoke the methods in the way you are doing because (a) it will be fragile in the face of further inheritance; and (b) you increase the maintenance effort by hardcoding references to classes.

Update: Here is an example showing how to use `super` to achieve this: http://ideone.com/u3si2

Also look at: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Update 2: Here's a little library for python 2 that adds a `__class__` variable and a no-args `super` to every method to avoid hardcoding the current name: https://github.com/marcintustin/superfixer

Comment: arent you still hardcoding the parent class with super?  how is `OtherClass.__init__(self)` different in terms of hardcoding than `super(otherclass,self).__init__()`  I dunno maybe im missing something obvious but they seem the same to me...

Comment: I understand the concerns you raise in point 2 and agree to proceed with caution!  Also, I edited the original post to confirm that I'm using Python 3.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Unless I'm mistaken, that doesn't arise with python 3. Further, if a class is going to definitely be a leaf class, you can do `type(self)` for the class; and if not, you only repeat the current class name, not the superclass name.

Comment: @MatthewLund I still don't understand why you're not using `super`. It really will make your life simpler.

Comment: @marcin ok I'll buy that ... not sure how super call fn on both parents but I have not even touched python 3 yet

Comment: @JoranBeasley Not sure what you mean. `super` calls the next method found in the MRO. The point of new-style classes is to allow this to be done in a linear fashion.

Comment: I mean I would expect it to print the info for A and B in attached example which is what it looks like he wants .... (http://ideone.com/2dhJU) as in example 2 (http://ideone.com/lvVCx)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Like in Python 2, both classes would need to call super.

Comment: so then you do still need to hardcode the class name in? I dont see much gain by using super instead the alternative...maybe you could whip up a quick example the shows the pro's of using super? I feel like im missing something fundamental.

Comment: ahhh there it all clicks now i get it!  that is handy thanks!

Comment: @JoranBeasley Here's another one: http://ideone.com/u3si2 check out how the exception handler works in the second case!

Comment: thats great ... its like magic how B catches the Error ...  man thats a nice feature.. can i import that from future in python2.6 ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley It basically works in python 2.6, except that you have to do `super(<currentclassname>, self)`.

Comment: oh man .. i feel stupid ive been using that wrong for years now,calling on the class i inherited from instead of my own class...

Comment: @JoranBeasley It does something slightly different. Anyway, one of the main criticisms of python's (2.x) super has always been that it has been unnecessarily confusing, and leads to mistakes like that.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Here's a little library I made to avoid hardcoding names in py 2.x: https://github.com/marcintustin/superfixer

Comment: @JoranBeasley I also just added the python 3-style no-args super.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16373/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-marcin)

Comment: @Marcin can you pop in that chat when you have time?